# Opening any webpage from terminal using the web browser of choice

Tags: terminal, firefox, browser, web

I have a very simple question. I usually launch my web browser from the terminal using e.g.

```
firefox &
```

I would like to know if I can also launch it to a specific website like google.com. Even better to launch it from the terminal using one of my favourites in the toolbar. 
Any ideas how to do this?
Cheers

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: Good to know I can find answers as simply as that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To launch a specific website like google.com : `firefox google.com`

To manage your favorites from the terminal, you need an additional CLI tools, e,g: [buku](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/buku/buku.1.en.html)

> buku - Bookmark manager like a text-based mini-web
>
> buku is a command-line utility to store, tag, search and organize bookmarks.

You can import your bookmarks through:

```
buku -i bookmarks.html
```

To list them:

```
bku --print
```

To search:

```
buku -s word
```

see `man buku` , `buku --help`  and [buku on github](https://github.com/jarun/buku).

Comment: I will look for the bookmanager tool buku. Thanks for the tip